# Primary key and composite unique index behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, membership, composite-primary-key

I'm doing a little custom membership system and i'm having issues. I have these tables (users, roles, applications, membership).

I want to do this:

Users

```
|UserId | ApplicationId | Username | ...
|1      | 1             | abc      | ...
|1      | 2             | abcd     | ...
```

"Is the same user in several apps, despite the different username"

Roles

```
|RoleId | ApplicationId | rolename | ...
|1      | 1             | xxx      | ...
|1      | 2             | xxx      | ...
```

"Is the same role in several apps"

With userid/roleid primary key and userid/roleid-applicationid composite unique index i know the system won't allow me to create the user in two applications.

I tried to do with composite primary keys but is a head ache after to make correct FKs because membership table needs to recognize application too (one user can have several credentials for several apps).

What is the best way to do, if is it possible?

Comment: What does connect users with roles? A user belongs to several roles? A user has always the same role for a certain application? What kind of relation there are between these two entities and where is stored this information?

Comment: There are another table userinroles (like asp.net membership, more or less), but i need user correlation between different apps.

Comment: One user can have more than one role, users can have several roles in several applications-same or not-. The usersinroles store the relations 1-to-many of users and roles (obviusly).

Comment: How/why does "membership table needs to recognize application too" cause a "headache to make correct FKs"? What does a row in the membership table look like & mean? Also re "won't allow me to create the user in two applications" Do you mean, to have the same user id twice in one application?